# Ubuntu cannot get past installation

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, 64-bit, guest-additions

I have a 64-bit laptop that runs on Windows 10. I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS through Virtual Box. When I try to install it will stop running right after I hit 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu'. When I look at 'Session information' the download is not going (CPU is at 0% along with almost everything else). I also try to install guest additions and it keeps giving me an error.

I have uninstalled Ubuntu from virtual box and installed it back erasing anything along with it. I have turned off all windows settings such as hyper-v and others. I have also enabled Hyper Virtualization in my computers system. Not sure where to go from here...

update: I have gotten to the page where it asked for me to make a login but soon stops and gives me the message that something is wrong with the system and they are sending info to a developer to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you verify your ISO after download to ensure it was perfect?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  You also weren't specific as to which 18.04 you are using, ie. server? desktop? or other? then 18.04? 18.04.1? 18.04.2? etc (these indicate kernel & software stack in use; vbox can have issues with newer stacks if newer than vbox itself).  Most problems I've experienced with `virtualbox` are settings in the host vbox setup

Comment: Hi thank you for answering! I am using ubuntu-18.04.4b desktop amd64. I did not verify ISO but I will try again. I uninstalled my virtual box and am installing it again to see if that helps